# For a Gatsby Starter - why do some npm packages "want" an older package version instead of the latest package version

Tags: gatsby, package-management

Several packages that I utilize in my gatsby site have packages that say an older version is Wanted.
I haven't been able to find good answers as to why some packages "want" to update and others don's "want" to update.

What harm is there in upgrading? What risk is there in NOT upgrading to the latest?

[image: NPM Outdated List - Wanted vs. Latest]